# cannot read property 'push' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I have a page which works on my localhost.. when I put t on a remote server, it gave an error. the code which returns the error is

```
  var $app_list = localStorage.getItem('LsAppList');
  var AppListJson = JSON.parse($app_list);
      AppListJson.push({ 
        "extapp_id": appdetail.get("addAppId"),
        "desc": appdetail.get("addAppName"),
        "device_no": appdetail.get("devicenoValue"),
        "validation_key": appdetail.get("activationkeyValue") 
    });
```

the console log is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
addToJson EncigoHome.js:126
n.extend.trigger kendo.mobile.min.js:9
s.extend._release kendo.mobile.min.js:15
i._userEvents.o.UserEvents.tap kendo.mobile.min.js:15
n.extend.trigger kendo.mobile.min.js:9
l.extend.notify kendo.mobile.min.js:13
u.extend._trigger kendo.mobile.min.js:13
u.extend.end kendo.mobile.min.js:13
l.extend._eachTouch kendo.mobile.min.js:13
l.extend._end kendo.mobile.min.js:13
arguments.length.t.(anonymous function) kendo.mobile.min.js:10
b.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:9593
v.handle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) is per domain (more specifically [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). The `localStorage` associated with the remote domain does not have access to the values stored in the `localStorage` associated with your localhost.

You should check to see if there is a stored value and fallback to a default one or treat the error:

```
var $app_list = localStorage.getItem('LsAppList');
var AppListJson = $app_list != null ? JSON.parse($app_list) : [];
//...
```

More verbose:

```
var $app_list = localStorage.getItem('LsAppList'),
    AppListJson;
if ($app_list != null) {
    AppListJson = JSON.parse($app_list);
} else {
    // treat no LsAppList stored case
    // you could show a message or set it to a default value
    AppListJson = [];
}
```

This "no previously stored data" scenario will happen whenever the user clears his browser data or switches browsers/devices as well, so it must be treated properly.

---

The root cause of the error, as you've probably figured out already, is that `localStorage.getItem(key)` returns `null` when no value is stored for the given `key` in the current domain. Then `JSON.parse(null) === null` and `null.push()` throws.

---

Just as a nitpick, I'd suggest reviewing your variables naming:

- Don't use `PascalCase` naming for non-constructors.
- Don't mix `camelCase` with underline naming conventions.
- Recommended read: [Idiomatic.js naming](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/#naming).

And also, `AppListJson` is not JSON, it is a native array. JSON can only exist in string context, that is, your `$app_list` is JSON. More in-depth explanation about JSON/not JSON: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1):

The `.push()` method can only be used on arrays.

It seems that you don't have the item stored in `localStorage`, which is why it is returning `null`